# CodeIgniter - Login form on each page

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

Ive run into a little problem with an application im trying to write with CodeIgniter, basically i want to have a login form on each page up the very top of the site, but im finding it difficult to figure out the logic with the validation function.

From my understanding, the validation rules ( set_rules ) have to be set from the controller, now if i want a login form on each page, does this mean i have to set the rules on each and every controller i write? this seems a little odd. can i set the validation rules from inside the view?

What i have at the moment is one view for the login box, which i call from my view with the

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/members_login'); ?>
```

command.

Any help or guidance on this would be great .... im quite stuck.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

No, you only have to set the rules in the controller function that **recieves/processes** the login form.  I generally keep a dedicated "Auth" controller to execute related operations like login/logout/reset password/etc...

for layout, you can just include it in the consistant header, but just point the form at your `controller/function` that processes the login.

For login forms though, I'm not sure why you'd want to "validate" them.  Either the user/pass matches up or it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes on my mind is to create basic layout for all of your pages which will load lets say 5,6 other files and build view for each page.
Some of these parts will be called on every page, like header, navigation... so you can use your login form in these parts and it will be loaded on every request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like AJAX via javascript to authenticate any user login. Basically the login button would be handled by an onclick event which would get the details of the button and pass it to your "Auth" (or Login or maybe UserAuth - up to you to decide) controller which would do the validation..

Answer (score -1):

If you *really* want the login form on every page, you could create your own My_Controller and do the form validation in the constructor.  Alternatively, as you said, you can do it in the view also.  CI doesn't force adherence to MVC.  If putting the code into your view would make for quicker development and easier maintenance, there is no reason not to do so.

Comment: Form validation in the constructor? ... huh?  Non-adherence to quality, purposeful standards because no one "forces" it is just a bad idea over all.